# How should i edit WHERE clause in SQL query to get desired result?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say i have two tables called "Videos" and "Reviews"

```
Videos:
int: video_id (PK)
String: video_name
.
.

Reviews:
int: review_id (PK)
int: video_id (FK)
String: review
.
.
```

In a scenario where i want to get all videos and their related reviews, i use the query:

```
"SELECT * FROM Videos v, Reviews r WHERE v.video_id = r.review_id"
```

But this query only returns the videos with a review, the videos without a review is not returned, but i also need them.

How should i edit the query to see videos without a review too?

Example result:

```
(video_id), (video_name), (review_id), (review)
1, "videoName", 1, "review1"
2, "videoName2", NULL, NULL
```

Thank you for your answers and comments. (sorry for the typo)

Comment: See [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you have some typos there - Travels or Videos
Nevertheless, here is the query based on your posted query:

```
SELECT * FROM Travels t left join Reviews r on t.travel_id = r.review_id
```

Just a left join will do the trick.

Comment: thanks for the upvote. Accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: I can't accept as an answer, OP can (it should be Videos and recommendation is to list all the fields instead of shortcutting with *).

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I can only accept one answer, so i accept Sudhir's as he answered earlier.

Comment: I thought OP had upvoted, so thanks to you @CetinBasoz

Comment: Also it should have been "Videos", not "Travels". That's my bad, i made a mistake, sorry for that.

Comment: @EmreTuran, it happens, no worries

Answer (score 2):

You use a "Left Join":

```
select v.video_id, v.video_name, r.review_id, r.review
from Videos v 
left join Reviews r on v.video_id = r.video_id;
```

(Your sample code is using old style join and it should really be the new style changing LEFT to INNER in the sample code)